# SQL - UPDATE CASE without a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, esri

bit of a novice here.  I am trying to write an update query on a versioned view (table 'v') of an esri sde database in SQL Server.  I update the view using data gathered from other processes and stored in table 'j'.

The view has an Instead of Update Trigger so I created this query using a subquery to avoid joining the view,  which would create and error with the Trigger.

```
UPDATE v
SET v.ma =
  (SELECT j.mc FROM j
   WHERE j.key = v.key
   AND j.ma <> j.mc);
```

This query works except that there are null records in 'j.mc' that I do not want to update 'v.ma'

I have attempted to use this CASE statement to get around that.

```
UPDATE v
SET v.ma =
  (CASE
       WHEN j.mc IS NOT NULL AND j.ma <> j.mc
       THEN (SELECT j.mc FROM j WHERE j.key = v.key)
       ELSE j.ma
   END)
   FROM j;
```

Unfortunately there are two problems I know of with this CASE statement. One, there is an implied join with 'v' and 'j' which creates an error with the Trigger.  Two, the subquery returns more than one value which is not allowed as part of CASE. I have been struggling to come up with a way to get around these two issues therefore:

1. Is there a way to make this CASE statement work?
2. If not should I be approaching this problem a different way, for instance an IF..ELSE or a CURSOR?

Comment: best to provide a sample data and desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your update:

```
UPDATE v
    SET v.ma = (SELECT j.mc
                FROM j
                WHERE j.key = v.key AND j.ma <> j.mc
               );
```

> This query works except that there are null records in 'j.mc' that I do not want to update 'v.ma'

This explanation is wrong.  The `WHERE` clause is filtering out any cases when `j.mc` is `NULL`.  Instead, the query is returning no rows.

The traditional way to handle this is by filtering these out.  Because you are using a correlated subquery, `exists` in the `where` is a solution:

```
UPDATE v
    SET v.ma = (SELECT j.mc
                FROM j
                WHERE j.key = v.key AND j.ma <> j.mc
               )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM j
                  WHERE j.key = v.key AND j.ma <> j.mc
                 );
```

If `j.mc` really can be `NULL`, you can express this as:

```
    WHERE (SELECT j.mc
           FROM j
           WHERE j.key = v.key AND j.ma <> j.mc
          ) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That is very interesting, I have never seen the 'SELECT 1'  function before.  It does solve the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your update statement. try below.

```
UPDATE v
SET ma =
  (CASE
       WHEN j.mc IS NOT NULL AND j.ma <> j.mc
       THEN j.mc
       ELSE j.ma
   END)
   FROM v
   left join j on
     v.key = j.key
```

or maybe

```
UPDATE v
SET ma =
  (CASE
       WHEN j.mc IS NOT NULL AND j.ma <> j.mc
       THEN (SELECT top 1 j.mc FROM j WHERE j.key = v.key)
       ELSE j.ma
   END)
```